# Using publish_{custom-post-type} hook for custom post type to update meta doesn't work

Tags: wordpress

I am using publish_{custom-post-type} hook to update meta of the post that has just been published. The post-type is jobboard-post-jobs. Why isn't it working?

```
add_action('publish_jobboard-post-jobs', 'when_new_job_published');
function when_new_job_published( $post_id, $post ) {
    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'meta_key_name', 'updated text for meta value' );
}
```

what am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass a number of arguments the function accepts.

```
add_action( 'publish_jobboard-post-jobs', 'when_new_job_published', 10, 2 );
function when_new_job_published( $post_id, $post ) {
    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'meta_key_name', 'updated text for meta value' );
}
```